# How can I filter dataGridView by checking multiple items in CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I have this code to filter my dataGridView using the checkedListBox. Every time the user checks a box in the checkedListBox, the dataGridView automatically updates to show only data related to the checked name (e.g. filtered by checked name = "John") and it works pretty well.

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
                DataTableCollection tables = myDatabaseDataSet.Tables;
                DataView view = new DataView(tables[0]);
                BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
                source.DataSource = view;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
                source.Filter = "myColumnName ='" + checkedListBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
        }
```

Now the question is, how could I make it so multiple items in the checkedListBox are checked and in turn dataGridView updates by showing only the names checked (e.g. checked names in the checkedListBox are "John" and "Jane")?

The above code gives me the following result:

[Code Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqDp4.png)

What I want to achieve is this (mocked picture):

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntjsz.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The name cant be John **and* Jane.    use OR

Comment: There has to be a primary sort (you cannot sort by John and Jane equally) you could sort by John, then a secondary sort by Jane; is that what you're after?

Comment: What I'm looking for is to have a datagridview with all names filtered but the ones that have a check mark in the checkedListBox. The code above already brings one name at a time. I want multiple names at a time.

Comment: @StevenByrne yes, for as long as the datagridview shows both names together in the same datagridview list.

Comment: If kalamazoowho's answer doesn't solve your problem, please update your question with desired results as I am a bit confused as to what you are looking to achieve. Do you want to change columns or sort the rows of data?
If you are trying to SORT by names, John, then Jane, then Bill, the Katie that will be different than if you want John Jane Bill and Katie to all display and exclude all other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you will have a database that will result in some form of "Select distinct name from database" to populate a checkedListBox. So now you'll have to add something like:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++) 
{
    CheckState st = checkedListBox.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox.Items.IndexOf(i));
    if(st == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        int selected = checkedListBox.SelectedIndex;
        if (selected != -1)
        {
            names.Add(checkedListBox.Items[selected].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The result of that will be a list of the items in checkedListBox that are checked. You can then use that with the code i gave previously to filter. Just replace the hardcoded names with the checked list strings.

```
string filterString = "";
int count = 0;
foreach (name in names)
{
    if (count != 0)
    {
        filterString += " OR Responsible = '" + name + "'";
    }
    else
    {
        filterString += "Responsible = '" + name + "'";
    }
    count += 1;
}
```

Now you have a string that can be used as a filter for creating the DataView:

```
DataView view = new DataView(tables[0], filterString, "Responsible Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

This should filter the table when it becomes a DataView as opposed to after, based on the checkBox states.

Final event:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    DataTableCollection tables = myDatabaseDataSet.Tables;

    //
    // Place all my code here
    //

    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = view;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
}
```

Comment: The idea is to have the end user filter the table by names as needed using a checkedListBox. The list of names vary depending on what's in Access so I can't have hardcoded names in the list.

Comment: Please check my updated question. I need the end user to check the boxes that will in turn, filter the dataGridView.

Comment: I reordered my answer above. It should do exactly what you are trying to do. Put it in an event that is called anytime a box is checked or unchecked. I believe it's the event you posted your code in.